# c++ function pointers giving runtime error when passed to push_heap

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11

I'm implementing Djikstra's shortest path algorithm and using a priority queue to determine which node to visit next, but I can't use std::priority_queue because this application requires the heap to be rebuilt in place.  I wrote my own wrapper for the functions `std::make_heap()`, `std::push_heap()`, and `std::pop_heap()` and i'm passing my own comparator to them, but it returns a null pointer error during runtime.  I have a feeling I'm either not actually passing the function pointer correctly or that the function pointer isnt being initialized correctly.

here's the code for initializing the function pointer

```
bool ShortestDistToHere(const Node& lhs, const Node& rhs){
    return distances[lhs.xpos][lhs.ypos] < distances[rhs.xpos][rhs.ypos];
}
bool (*shortestDist)(const Node& lhs, const Node& rhs) = &shortestDistToHere;
```

and here's the function call using it

```
push_heap(queueVector.begin(), queueVector.end(), shortestDist);
```

Edit: In the comments I metioned that there was an error when it tried to call something or other on a predicate.  Well, it turns out that Visual Studio 11 doesn't follow C++ specifications quite all the way (or the documentation is just obscure) cause in the reference it said that the third argument to make_heap was a function pointer or function object, but it was in fact a predicate that it needed.  Unless a function object is a predicate, then I've just been going about this the wrong way the entire time.

Comment: What is "distances"? Can you show its declaration/initialization?

Comment: Distances is an int array[250][200] that contains the current shortest distance to get to a node, the next node to be visited is that with the shortest distance, as in a graph with all nonzero edges it is guaranteed that that is the shortest path to that node.

Comment: If so, you might be looking at out-of-bounds access into the array and not necessarily something to do with the function pointers at all.

Comment: I followed the trace back (the error gave me a file and line number) and all of the errors were caused in visual studio's algorithm.cpp file on this line `_DEBUG_POINTER(_Pred);` where _Pred is the predicate used to determine the ordering.

Comment: Suppose there are three edges out of start node `S` to nodes `A`, `B` and `C`, with weights 1, 10 and 100. The heap arranges them in the order `[A, B, C]`. Then you investigate node `A`, and discover that there's an edge with weight 1 to `C`. You then update `distance[C] = 2`. Suddenly, under the now-changed comparison predicate, the sequence `[B, C]` is no longer a valid heap - but you continue to treat it as one. At this point, your program exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: Exactly, which is why I'm not using `std::priority_queue` but instead wrapped the functions on my own.  The undefined behavior is no longer undefined if, after `distance[C]` is updated you call `std::make_heap(queueVector.begin(), queueVector.end(), <comparator>)`  The problem i was having in this question was that what i was putting in for <comparator> threw no compile time errors but a ton of weird runtime errors.  It turned out that the actual format was the same as for using `std::priority_queue` but just not in the angle brackets.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to call `push_heap()` is

```
push_heap(queueVector.begin(), queueVector.end(), ShortestDistToHere());
```

it needs an instance of the functor object.